# Python object inspection get param values set by user

Tags: python

Say my class looks as follows:

```
class abc:
    def __init__(self, a = 1, b = None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

Now user creates an object as:
    obj = abc(2)

which means user wants to use default value of b and a value of 2 for a.
How can I use object inspection to get a list of parameters and the values set explicitly by the user at the time of object creation?

Comment: `>>> vars(obj) - {'a': 2, 'b': None}`?

Comment: You mean in the constructor?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. There is no way to look at an instance of `abc` with `a == 2` and `b == None` in a way that would tell you whether it was created by `abc(2)` or `abc(2, None)`.